# Guardar form con registro dinámico - con laravel

Tags: laravel, formularios

necesito ayuda alguien me podria ayudar  ? 
-- Este es el caso, tengo un formulario tipo tabla ademas dinámica y necesito guardarla en una base de datos, el número de registros no es fijo ya que puedo añadir uno nuevo según necesite, no tengo idea como hacer esto alguien podria sugerirme algo,  ? es un formulario de solicitud 

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ponle de name a los inputs `producto[]['nombre']`,  `producto[]['marca']`, y en el controlador recorrelo con un foreach

```
foreach($request->producto as $producto){
      dd($producto['nombre']);
}
```